# Can I change my devices from for example sda1 to sda2?

Tags: partitioning, devices

I want to change the numbers of my partitons. I want to change /dev/sda1 into /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda5 into /dev/sda1.
I hope someone can help me to change it.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change them you'd have to move the partitions around.

You can only have 4 primary partitions so:

Devices are named by their placement in the partition table of the disk ex:

sda1 is the first primary partition 
sda2 is the second primary partition
sda3 is the third primary partition
sda4 is the fourth primary partition

Extended partition will take up a space on the primary partition table for the extended container like /dev/sda2 could be the start of an extended container therefore linux names the first extended partition sda5  to not conflict with the 4 primary partition device names.